# Appium and Selenium fail to connect when "Use current location" permission popup appears

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I am attempting to automate iOS testing with Appium. I have an app that requires user location and requests location permission on first launch. When I try to connect selenium to a fresh install, it fails when the popup appears. When I manually accept the popup, Seleium and Appium connect without fail and the test is able to continue.

This is a copy of the server output:

```
error: Instruments did not launch successfully, failing session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Instruments did not launch successfully--please check your app paths or bundle IDs and try again
info: Responding to client with error: {"status":6,"value":{"message":"A session is either terminated or not started","origValue":"Instruments did not launch successfully--please check your app paths or bundle IDs and try again"},"sessionId":"faccc84b-fa8e-4137-ad77-f0c79d09b045"}
POST /wd/hub/session 500 13605ms - 270
debug: - - - "POST /wd/hub/session HTTP/1.1" 500 270 "-" "Ruby"
info: Clearing out appium devices
```

and a copy of the selenium output:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError:
       A session is either terminated or not started
```

and I am initializing Selenium with the following command:

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities, :url => server_url)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue in Instruments. When the location services pops up within about 8 seconds of app launch, UIAutomation doesn't handle the popup for some reason. See [this discussion on the Appium mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/appium-discuss/location/appium-discuss/491folM-Qaw/AyaLym1V81IJ) for more information.

The only solution proposed so far is to delay the location services check until ~8s after app launch.

Comment: I had posted on that thread as well, seems as though there is no other way to get around this issue if it is a limitation of UIAutomation itself

Answer (score 2):

There has been an appium update for this. Simply add the capability to always accept these alerts to avoid failures anywhere in the app. Java example:

```
        capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  To get it working I added 2 capabilities to Appium

```
    caps = {
        "locationServicesAuthorized" => true
        "bundleId" => "com.domain.myproject"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try:

start your app, accept location manually, then copy file from path to your test folder.

path - /Users/your_username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Library/Caches/locationd/clients.plist

then each time before starting your test, copy that file back to that location and you will not see Location Popup.

BR.
Aleks.